# Regex to allow spaces in string - bash

Tags: regex, bash

I can't get a string with spaces to validate. It works without spaces, but when I include a space in the string it fails. I have googled furiously but can't get it to work.

```
if [[ $string =~ ^"[A-Za-z ]"$ ]]; then
    # true
else 
    # false
fi
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here...

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](https://ideone.com/M93zW9). You need `'^[A-Za-z ]*$'` to match a string that can contain 0 or more letters or spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a variable to store your regex:

```
re='^[A-Za-z ]+$'
```

Then use it as:

```
[[ "string" =~ $re ]] && echo "matched" || echo "nope"
matched

[[ "string with spaces" =~ $re ]] && echo "matched" || echo "nope"
matched
```

If you want inline regex then use:

```
[[ "string with spaces" =~ ^[A-Za-z\ ]+$ ]] && echo "matched" || echo "nope"
matched
```

Or else use `[[:blank:]]` property:

```
[[ "string with spaces" =~ ^[A-Za-z[:blank:]]+$ ]] && echo "matched" || echo "nope"
matched
```

Answer (score -3):

I should instead use following regex if its always space instead..

```
if [[ $string =~ ^"[A-Za-z ](\s)"$ ]]; then
    # true
else 
    # false
fi
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Those quotes are wrong and even if they weren't there, this pattern wouldn't permit a string with any number of characters other than 2.