# Validate string for file characters including space

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have the following code:

```
if      ! [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z._-]+$ ]]; then  
    echo "argument contains characters not valid for name file"
fi
```

All I want is to validate if the string has valid characters for valid file name (I know I should add test for beginning of file, and length afterwards).

**PROBLEM:**

As such, it does not validate strings with spaces in it.

So I need to include space in the regex, but nothing of the following works:

```
[[ $1 =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z ._-]+$ ]]   >>  syntax error
[[ $1 =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z\t._-]+$ ]]   >> still do not pass spaces
[[ $1 =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z\s._-]+$ ]]   >> still do not pass spaces
[[ $1 =~ "^[0-9a-zA-Z ._-]+$" ]]   >>  syntax error
```

I'm not sure what more to try.

So far, I come up with a quick and dirty thing:

```
myNewVar="${1// /}"
```

and do the tests with that, but that's far from elegant ...

Comment: Why is the final option not elegant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to allow spaces in string - bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501096/regex-to-allow-spaces-in-string-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`[:blank:]` character class](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
re='^[[:alnum:][:blank:]._-]+$'
if ! [[ $1 =~ $re ]]; then
```

Notice that I've move the regex into a separate variable<sup>1</sup>, and also introduced the `[:alnum:]` character class.

Instead of regular expressions, you could use parameter expansion to remove allowed characters and see if anything is left:

```
if [[ -n ${1//[[:alnum:][:blank:]._-]} ]]; then
    echo "illegal character found"
fi
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Mostly for portability reasons, but also to avoid quoting surprises (like the unquoted blank in your last example), see the [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) (section "Regular Expressions").

Comment: I swear i tried something like this and did not work. but indeed THAT EXACT way goes perfect !!  thanks a lot